# Java 8 is not maintaining the order while grouping

Tags: java-8, grouping, java-stream, collect

I m using Java 8 for grouping by data. But results obtained are not in order formed.

```
Map<GroupingKey, List<Object>> groupedResult = null;

        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(groupByColumns)) {

            Map<String, Object> mapArr[] = new LinkedHashMap[mapList.size()];

            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(mapList)) {
                int count = 0;
                for (LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map : mapList) {
                    mapArr[count++] = map;
                }
            }
            Stream<Map<String, Object>> people = Stream.of(mapArr);
            groupedResult = people
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> new GroupingKey(p, groupByColumns), Collectors.mapping((Map<String, Object> p) -> p, toList())));


public static class GroupingKey 

        public GroupingKey(Map<String, Object> map, List<String> cols) {

            keys = new ArrayList<>();

            for (String col : cols) {
                keys.add(map.get(col));
            }
        }

        // Add appropriate isEqual() ... you IDE should generate this
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final GroupingKey other = (GroupingKey) obj;
            if (!Objects.equals(this.keys, other.keys)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 7;
            hash = 37 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.keys);
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return keys + "";
        }

        public ArrayList<Object> getKeys() {
            return keys;
        }

        public void setKeys(ArrayList<Object> keys) {
            this.keys = keys;
        }

    }
```

Here i am using my class groupingKey by which i m dynamically passing from ux. How can get this groupByColumns in sorted form?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Not maintaining the order is a property of the `Map` that stores the result. If you need a specific `Map` behavior, you need to [request a particular `Map` implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-). E.g. [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) maintains the insertion order:

```
groupedResult = people.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    p -> new GroupingKey(p, groupByColumns),
    LinkedHashMap::new,
    Collectors.mapping((Map<String, Object> p) -> p, toList())));
```

---

By the way, there is no reason to copy the contents of `mapList` into an array before creating the `Stream`. You may simply call `mapList.stream()` to get an appropriate `Stream`.

Further, `Collectors.mapping((Map<String, Object> p) -> p, toList())` is obsolete. `p->p` is an identity mapping, so there’s no reason to request `mapping` at all:

```
groupedResult = mapList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    p -> new GroupingKey(p, groupByColumns), LinkedHashMap::new, toList()));
```

---

But even the `GroupingKey` is obsolete. It basically wraps a `List` of values, so you could just use a `List` as key in the first place. `List`s  implement `hashCode` and `equals` appropriately (but you *must not* modify these key `List`s  afterwards).

```
Map<List<Object>, List<Object>> groupedResult=
  mapList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    p -> groupByColumns.stream().map(p::get).collect(toList()),
    LinkedHashMap::new, toList()));
```

Comment: Thanx Holger u made my task vry simpler. But still i have issue that if i want to apply sorting in this only wid this groupedColumns then wat should i do?

Comment: The method `toList()` is undefined, is it Collections.toList?

Comment: @geneb. `Collectors.toList()`. You may use `import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;` to avoid repetitions of `Collectors.`, when combining collectors.

Answer (score 15):

Based on @Holger's great answer. I post this to help those who want to keep the order after grouping as well as changing the mapping.

Let's simplify and suppose we have a list of persons (int age, String name, String adresss...etc) and we want the names grouped by age while keeping ages in order:

```java
final LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<String> map = myList
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getAge())) //sort list by ages
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getAge()),
                        LinkedHashMap::new, //keeps the order
                        Collectors.mapping(p -> p.getName(), //map name
                                Collectors.toList())));
```