# Collectors.groupingBy() returns result sorted in ascending order java

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am sending result in descending order but I get output with ascending order

```
List<myEntity> myData = new ArrayList<>();
Map<Integer,List<myEntity>> myid = new LinkedHashMap<>();

try {
    myData = myService.getData(id); 
    myid = myData.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(myEntity::getDataId));
```

Here mydata is sorted by desc order but after creating collections by group data id my list get sorted with ascending order. I want my collection list to be descending order not ascending order.

Comment: Just reverse the list first.

Comment: can you give me example ?

Comment: `Collections.reverse(myData);`

Comment: It is not working for me..I am getting data in ascending order only ..i want my collection to be sorted in decsending order

Comment: Which part is not sorted? The `myid` map, or the `myEntity` inside the list?

Comment: Maybe try `Collectors.groupingBy(myEntity::getDataId, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @Hitobat You should post that comment as an answer, I think it's the correct solution to the problem

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As @Holger described in [Java 8 is not maintaining the order while grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764157/java-8-is-not-maintaining-the-order-while-grouping) 
, Collectors.groupingBy() returns a HashMap, which does not guarantee order.

Here is what you can do:

```
myid = myData.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyEntity::getDataId,LinkedHashMap::new, toList()));
```

Would return a `LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<MyEntity>>`. The order will also be maintained as the list used by collector is ArrayList.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner oh ! my bad , sorry i missed the point , i'll update the answer, tnx for saying

Comment: That’s still missing the point. You are sorting the lists, which do maintain the encounter order, without solving the actual problem of the *map* not maintaining the order.

Comment: Thank you for solution I used above code it is giving me my collection with reverse order but after sending data to UI side it is again showing in ascending order dont know what is wrong i am using  return ResponseEntity.ok(myidcollection);..can you please help me with this

Comment: @sandy I'm not a moderator, but it is my understanding that according to the rules of this site, you should ask a separate question asking that, linking to this question and answer. The problem might be that in the UI side they're using a HashMap instead of a LinkedHashMap, or who knows what... We need more context, this is why I'm asking you to ask a separate question.

Comment: Thank you I will ask new question

Answer (score 8):

`Collectors.groupingBy` returns a `HashMap` without any order as such (as to why you see "some order" is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52192853/1059372)). The correct way to do this is to specify the `Map` that preserve the order inside the `Collectors.groupingBy`:

```
myData.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
          MyEntity::getDataId,
          LinkedHashMap::new,
          Collectors.toList()     

))
```

Answer (score 4):

`collect(Collectors.groupingBy())` returns a new `Map` which overwrites the variable to your previous `LinkedHashMap`. Your initial assignment is therefore futile. The exact type returned is undefined by the specs but in my test run it returned a `HashMap`. (Never assume this will always be the case across different versions and brands of Java!)

But the main issue is that you're storing `Integer` as keys. If the values of those keys is smaller than the modulus of the table inside the `HashMap`, they will just appear ordered (because the `hashCode` of an `Integer` is just it;s value). When I tested with 1000 `Integer` values of 0..999, the hashtable (the array as part of the inner workings of `HashMap`) appeared to be of size 2048. (Again, undocumented so don't assume it!)

**In summary**, the reason you see the results in ascending order is because of an implementation artifact, not because there's a specific reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need reverse order of map. So In `java 8` , i solved with this.

```
myData = myService.getData(id);
myid = myData.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(myEntity::getDataId));

Map<Integer, List<myEntity>> finalMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
myid.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, List<myEntity>>comparingByKey()
                .reversed())
        .forEachOrdered(e -> finalMap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
System.out.println("FINAL RESULT : " + finalMap);
```

`Entryset` gives us `Integers` of this map of `myid`. So **sort** and **get** from first map which is `myid` and **put** in `finalMap`

Comment: order of which list ? But he said now ascending order but he wants descending order. I solved this situtation

Comment: How can i know service's return , he can sort i think or provide sorted ? i wrote this code according to questions. And I sort this keyset and map. It does work correctly, can u try? i tried with lots of  odds

Comment: In the question, OP says textually `Here mydata is sorted by desc order`, so the list `mydata` is already sorted in desc order. The problem is that after grouping, the map is not sorted any more. This is because the map is a `HashMap` instead of a `LinkedHashMap`, which preserves insertion order.

Comment: `.sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, List<myEntity>>comparingByKey()
                .reversed())` this line provide us sorting

Comment: Thank you for solution ...I used above code and I am getting in descending order.. but dont know in UI side its showing in ascending order only I m using ResponseEntity to send mydata .... so Can you please help with this ?  Thank you again

Comment: Backend never knows frontend. U can send any order. if ui wants to show in asc order, it can sort in js side or whatelse. Backend should ignore this sorting in shortly.