# ResponseEntity returns result sorted in ascending order java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, collections

I am wokring on collections

here is my code

```
List<myEntity> myData = new ArrayList<>();
Map<Integer,List<myEntity>> myid = new LinkedHashMap<>();

try {
myData = myService.getData(id); 
myid = myData.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(myEntity::getDataId));
```

I changed my code to

```
myid = myData.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyEntity::getDataId,LinkedHashMap::new, toList()));
```

it is working as i wanted myid in descending order not ascending order

but when I used `return ResponseEntity.ok(myid );`

it again return me ascending order collection I want collection descending order 
Response Body shows it is ascending order not descending order

here is reference of my previous question 
[Previosly asked question and got answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52192078/collectors-groupingby-returns-result-sorted-in-ascending-order-java)

Comment: So `myid` is sorted correctly but `ResponseEntity.ok(myid )` returns the wrong order?

Comment: yes, myid is sorted .. but front end gets ascending order again

Comment: So the problem is either that `ResponseEntity.ok(myid )` does something to the ordering (did you check?) or your frontend does something (which we don't know anything about except that you're using Spring MVC).

Comment: in Swagger Response body I can see result it is ascending order

Comment: Well, did you step through your code with a debugger to check where exactly it gets sorted the wrong way?